# Subquery returns more than one in row in PL/SQL stored procedure

Tags: plsql

I am a complete novice to PL/SQL and this is an attempt to start writing stored procedures . The case is i want to simply find out inside my stored procedure what is the name of the employee who is getting the highest salary for a particular department (which is passed as a parameter to the stored procedure).

Below is a screen shot of my tables:

[image: Department tables]

[image: Employee table]

The code of my stored procedure is as follows :

```
create or replace procedure High_salary(Dept_Name IN varchar2)
/*RETURN varchar2 */
AS
EMP_NAME_var varchar2(100) := '';
Begin
dbms_output.put_line('****'||Dept_Name);
select EMP_NAME INTO EMP_NAME_var
from(
select EMP_NAME,rank() over(order by salary desc) rn from employee 
where DEPT_CD=(select DEPT_CD from DEPARTMENT where DEPT_NAME=Dept_Name)) a where rn=1;
/*RETURN EMP_NAME_var;*/
END;
```

when i run this i get this error:

```
Connecting to the database LOCAL_DEV_DB.
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
ORA-06512: at "LOCAL_DEV_DB.HIGH_SALARY", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 6
****'Technology'
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database LOCAL_DEV_DB.
```

However when i run the subquery separate it gets only one row as expected :

```
select EMP_NAME 
from(
select EMP_NAME,rank() over(order by salary desc) rn from employee 
where DEPT_CD=(select DEPT_CD from DEPARTMENT where DEPT_NAME='Technology')) a where rn=1;
```

[image: Result]

Can someone please point out what i am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely comes from the fact that your variable name is the same as the field name. In the procedure, it is comparing Dept_Name with itself, and unsurprisingly, all rows match.

In the procedure, try naming the variable `DeptNameVar` or similar, update the reference in the query, and see if that helps.

Comment: Changed the parameter name to Dept_Name_var. The issue now I'm getting while running the procedure is : Data not found. Although while running the query separately the query is fetching proper result.

Comment: Changing the variable name has worked. No changes made to my code except just the variable name. and it returns proper result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would express your logic as a join between the two tables.  Then, use `ROW_NUMBER` to identify the record for a given department corresponding to the employee with the highest salary.

```
create or replace procedure High_salary (Dept_Name IN varchar2)
AS
    EMP_NAME_var varchar2(100) := '';
    Begin dbms_output.put_line('****'||Dept_Name);
    select EMP_NAME INTO EMP_NAME_var
    from
    (
        select e.EMP_NAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.SALARY DESC) rn
        FROM employee e
        INNER JOIN department d
            ON e.DEPT_CD = d.DEPT_CD
        WHERE d.DEPT_NAME = Dept_Name
    ) t
    where rn = 1

END;
```

The problem with your current approach is not necessarily the `WHERE` clause, which should be working, but rather than you are using the `RANK` function.  `RANK` would return 1 should two or more employees be tied for the highest salary.

By using `ROW_NUMBER`, you ensure that the subquery would only ever return a single row.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. However, I'm little confused since the query I used previously was giving proper result, when tested separately(without Pl/Sql). Why the JOIN is essential here, is it always advisable while using Select * INTO clause?

Comment: @user1867151 My guess is that `RANK` is the problem.  I see some ties in your sample data between two or more employees having the highest salary in the same department.  `ROW_NUMBER` guarantees that only one record would ever be returned from the subquery.

Comment: ok. Good to know that. But Rank is working in this case and i'm getting the proper answer even with the Rank() function. The JOIN is somehow making a difference is what I can see. Any insights?

Comment: What I stated is the only explanation of which I can think.  There may be some problem with your data which we can't see right now.  In any case, my answer is a legitimate way to handle your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because of this part of the statement 
select EMP_NAME,rank() over(order by salary desc) rn from employee.
You are pulling two columns one is EMP_NAME and other is rank() over(order by salary desc) rn.That's why you are getting that error.
Please modify the subquery such that you only select emp_name.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I modified the query and tried pulling both the columns now in the below fashion. Select col1, col2 into col1_var, col2_var from (subquery which returns 2 columns). However, I'm getting the same error.                      ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
ORA-06512: at "LOCAL_DEV_DB.HIGH_SALARY", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 6

Comment: don't pull two columns,just one is required.U just need have EMP_NAME .just pull that column

Comment: Also please can you share me the output you are getting when you run the subsquey only.

Comment: Also your rank will return more rows,use row_number().

Comment: select EMP_NAME 
from(
select EMP_NAME,rank() over(order by salary desc) rn from employee 
where DEPT_CD=(select DEPT_CD from DEPARTMENT where DEPT_NAME='Technology')) a where rn=1;                                                                   Output: Ravan

Comment: Please use row number() instead of rank() and it will work.

Comment: select EMP_NAME INTO EMP_NAME_var
from(
select EMP_NAME from(
select EMP_NAME,row_number() over(order by salary desc) rn from employee 
where DEPT_CD=(select DEPT_CD from DEPARTMENT where DEPT_NAME=Dept_Name))) a where rn=1;
dbms_output.put_line('****'||EMP_NAME_var);                                                  
 This is also giving the same error. "Subquery returns more than one row".